# Dockerfile setting a home directory

Tags: pip, dockerfile, raspbian, slugify

I am writing a dockerfile, where one of its dependencies can only be installed only when a homedirectory exist, but how do I set something like that up?

```
ARG BUILD_FROM=raspbian/stretch:latest
FROM $BUILD_FROM


RUN apt-get -qq update \
    && apt-get -qq install -y --no-install-recommends \
        apt-transport-https \
        apt-utils \
        dirmngr \
        gnupg-curl \
        mpg123 \
        supervisor \
        unzip \
        curl \
        git \
        wget \
        python3 \

    && pip3 install -U setuptools && pip3 install utils\
    && pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

requirements.txt

```
slugify
google-api-python-client
oauth2client
esptool
```

this can only be installed using `pip3 install --user slugify` which requires an homedir which I can't setup..

Answer (score 0):

You can either create the dir manually by using a line like:

```
RUN mkdir /home/slugify
```

or if you need a full user with permissions etc you can run:

```
RUN adduser slugify
```

Read more at the [manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/adduser/adduser.8.sv.html)

Comment: @square in that case is the problem only the missing home directory or is there other parts to it such as a need to run as a specific user etc. If you show an error message we might be able to help more

Answer (score 0):

I think there should be an user home set by default.

However, you can change it using `usermod -d /newhome/username username`:

```
RUN mkdir /homedir
RUN usermod -d /homedir root
```

Maybe the program just needs an environment variable `HOME`:

```
RUN HOME=/homedir;<install command>
```